# RangeSlider problem with css3 transform scale

Tags: css, devextreme, rangeslider

I am trying to use RangeSlider in my web application, this is a web site of RangeSlider.
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxRangeSlider/

But there are problem on move slider, and it is connected to css3 transform scale.
You can check a problem in this link

https://jsfiddle.net/7L0q268e/

```
.dx-viewport{
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

There are some fix for this problem?

thanks for the help you can give me

Comment: why do you need scaling?

Comment: to make the content small you can style it like that, I did not get point of using the scale on your code.

Comment: i need to scale for view my web page on different aspect ratio screen, some other component work with css scale

Comment: if you want your web page on different aspect ratio screen, follow RWD

Comment: yes this a possibility. But there are possible solution with the component?

Comment: with browser zoom problem disappeared